# How to play video files from DB?

Tags: asp.net

> I have my asp.net website which play video from DB , i had the script
>   below but how to make file attribute get the video file from db .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jwplayer("PlayMP4Video").setup({
                file: "sp.flv",
                flashplayer: "player.swf"
            });
        });
    </script>



<div>
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe id="PlayMP4Video" width="215" height="160" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: else see this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Save-Retrieve-and-Play-MP4-Video-files-with-live-streaming-from-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: You can make HttpHandle to get the file from the DB to provide this for your page. Depending on the version of ASP.NET, you can create a Web API to stream this video as well.